# Process created by Kernel#system doesn't seem to have fully exited when the call returns

Tags: java, windows, jar, jruby, executable-jar

I'm writing a jruby application, run from within a Java jar, that is responsible for updating another application running as a windows service on the user's machine.  The relevant portion of the program that I'm having an issue with is as follows:

- The windows service downloads the updater.jar program, launches the updater.jar, then the windows service exits
- The updater.jar runs and invokes a windows .bat file to uninstall the windows service. The .bat file is located in the windows_service_root\bin\ directory. The .bat file is invoked via ruby's Kernel#system() method, e.g.:
  system('windows_service_root\bin\uninstall_service.bat')
- After system() has returned, I'm overwriting every file in windows_service_root\bin\ with newer copies of all the files that updater.jar has brought along with it, including 'uninstall_service.bat'

My problem is that, intermittently, I receive an error that uninstall_service.bat is still in use and cannot be overwritten, despite my expectation that when Kernel#system() has exited, the launched subprocess should have fully exited.

jruby 1.6.7.2 / Windows Server 2008 / java 1.7.0_40-b43

Thanks in advance for any help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're on latest of JRubies and alternatively try doing a `Spoon.spawn` (using the spoon gem) ... Windows is supported: https://github.com/headius/spoon/blob/master/lib/spoon.rb#L16

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug. You should file this as an issue at http://bugs.jruby.org.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's maybe not so much a bug, but just how Windows deals with files after a process terminates, such as is suggested in this question: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463927/windows-process-exit-and-file-socket-handles)